# How to push object array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

`loggedUser` as `object` in `users` index (unknown) variable:

```
// This is the users index of a variable containing multiple users which have a `docs` array.
users: [
    {id: '140255045', password: '72465091Be', email: 'a@gmail.com', tc: '1', dId: 1, name: 'Erkan', surname: 'Çalışkan', docs: []},
    {id: '1', password: '1', email: 'a@gmail.com', tc: '1', dId: 1, name: 'Erkan', surname: 'Çalışkan', docs: []},
    {id: '2', password: '2', email: 'a@gmail.com', tc: '1', dId: 2, name: 'Erkan', surname: 'Çalışkan', docs: []},
    {id: '3', password: '3', email: 'a@gmail.com', tc: '1', dId: 2, name: 'Erkan', surname: 'Çalışkan', docs: []}
]
```

This is the array I want to push into object:

```
var docs = [
    {
        type: '',
        piece: '',
        insti: '',
        desc: '',
        selected: '',
        date: ''
    }
];

var a = this.docs.push({
    type: this.docs.type,
    piece: this.docs.piece,
    insti: this.docs.insti,
    desc: this.docs.desc,
    selected: this.docs.selected,
    date: today
});

this.loggedUser.docs.push(a);

console.log(this.loggedUser);
```

> Error : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I want to push `docs` array to `loggedUser.docs` array.

Comment: your `loggedUser` looks like wha in your data object?

Comment: This seems syntactically incorrect, but it's hard to tell if it's just pieces of code stripped out from elswhere. It looks like you're half way through defining an object with properties of users and docs, but then you suddenly have function code without terminating the object definition? I would perhaps expect a comma after the docs definition and then maybe a function definition for the last bit? Otherwise what is the 'this' referring to?

Comment: BTW - The error basically means that it doesn't know what this.docs is - it is undefined. The push part is irrelevant here until you sort that undefined bit out.

Answer (score 2):

Change the colon (`:`) to an equals sign (`=`)
The colon is used for assigning stuff to an id *within* an object or array.

```
users = [
    {id:'140255045',password:'72465091Be',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:1,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
    {id:'1',password:'1',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:1,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
    {id:'2',password:'2',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:2,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
    {id:'3',password:'3',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:2,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]}
  ]
```

Comment: i think `users` is data object property not a local variable

Answer (score 0):

If `users` is an index of a variable, your code should look like this:

```
// Schema for `this.loggeduser`
{
    id: '140255045',
    password: '72465091Be',
    email: 'a@gmail.com',
    tc: '1',
    dId:1,
    name: 'Erkan',
    surname: 'Çalışkan',
    docs:[]
}

// Declare docs as an `Array` object variable in `this` context.
this.docs = [
    {
        type: '',
        piece: '',
        insti: '',
        desc: '',
        selected: '',
        date: ''
    }
];

// Push an object into the declared array.
// By now `this.docs` should contain 2 objects.
this.docs.push({
    type: this.docs.type,
    piece: this.docs.piece,
    insti: this.docs.insti,
    desc: this.docs.desc,
    selected: this.docs.selected,
    date: today
});

// Push `this.docs` `Array` object.
// If `this.loggedUser` exists and has `docs` property of type `Array` this should work.
this.loggedUser.docs.push(this.docs);

console.log(this.loggedUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep users and docs within an object you can do it this way (I've simplified the end code with basic strings to show that it works). I've created another variable called obj to store you're object somewhere.

```js
var obj = {
 users : [
   {id:'140255045',password:'72465091Be',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:1,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
   {id:'1',password:'1',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:1,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
   {id:'2',password:'2',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:2,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
   {id:'3',password:'3',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:2,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]}
    ],
 
 docs: [{ type : '',
    piece : '',
    insti : '',
    desc : '',
    selected : '',
    date : ''}] 
}
 

obj.docs.push({ type : 'test',
    piece : 'test',
    insti : 'test',
    desc : 'test',
    selected : 'test',
    date : 'test'});
 
  
console.log(obj.docs);
```

You could also do this with a function within the same object like this

```js
var obj = {
 users : [
   {id:'140255045',password:'72465091Be',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:1,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
   {id:'1',password:'1',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:1,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
   {id:'2',password:'2',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:2,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]},
   {id:'3',password:'3',email:'a@gmail.com',tc:'1',dId:2,name:'Erkan',surname:'Çalışkan',docs:[]}
    ],
 
 docs: [{ type : '',
    piece : '',
    insti : '',
    desc : '',
    selected : '',
    date : ''}],
 
 a: function () {
  this.docs.push({ type : 'test',
    piece : 'test',
    insti : 'test',
    desc : 'test',
    selected : this.docs[0].selected,
    date : this.docs[0].selected});
  
 }
}
 

obj.a();
 
  
console.log(obj.docs);
```

Remember that when referencing the this.docs that it is returning an array so you'll need to make sure you put in index in there for it to refer to a particular object within that array (as I've done in this code on the last couple of values).